# Which edition of SQL Server express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I am looking to learn SQL server - specifically T-SQL programming, writing stored procedures etc and getting familiar.

I had a look at the MS site to download SQL Server express, however it gives me the below choices. Can someone please advise which should be the correct option considering my learning goal ?

- SQL Server Express with Tools (with LocalDB, Includes the database
  engine and SQL Server Management Studio Express)
- SQL Server Management Studio Express (Tools only)
- SQL Server Express LocalDB (MSI installer)
- SQL Server Express with Advanced Services (contains the database
  engine, Express Tools, Reporting Services, and Full Text Search)
- SQL Server Express (Containing only the database engine)

These are present on below site -

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Answer (score 8):

I would go for:

SQL Server Express with Tools (with LocalDB, Includes the database engine and SQL Server Management Studio Express)

This gives you MS SQL Express and the Management Studio which will give you all the playground to experiment.

Comment: Without question this is the version you want.  It's a pain when you install without the Management Studio (when you end up needing it)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to learn T-SQL programming then I would actually recommend [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx). It comes with SQL Server Express LocalDB included, and it integrates with Visual Studio. The tool is focused on T-SQL development and is the best way of writing T-SQL procedures and other T-SQL code that will ship as part of an application.